# Query execution order/optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Given the view

```
create view MyView as
select Id, ExpensiveFunction(Name) as Expr from MyTable
```

If used in the query

```
select *
from AnotherTable a 
  inner join MyView b on b.Id = a.Id
```

Is `ExpensiveFunction` computed for every row in `MyTable`, or is SQL Server smart enough to join to `AnotherTable` first, and then call `ExpensiveFunction` for only the filtered rows?

Would it behave differently if `MyView` is a subquery or TVF?

Comment: What does the execution plan says?

Comment: It's hypothetical. A meaningful test would be non-trivial to setup. I thought someone may know if SQL Server generally detects this kind of optimization.

Comment: In general I would expect it to, yes.  It generally determines the steps it needs to run, then evaluates which will be cheapest based on existing stats and runs those first.  The only way to know for sure is to test.

Comment: It's not a certainty, but it will generally be smart enough to do what you said, but you need to test the real situation to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExpensiveFunction` will only be called when it is relevant. If your final select statement does not even include it at all, the function will, in turn, not be called.

Similarly, if the final select only selects one tenth of the table, the function will only be called on that one tenth.

This works the same way in sub-queries and inline views. You could specify a function for a field in a sub-query, and if the field is never used, the function will never be executed.

It is true that **scalar functions are notoriously expensive**. It *might* be possible to reduce the overhead by instead using a table valued function:

```
SELECT 
  MyTable.*, 
  ExpensiveFunction.Value 
FROM 
  MyTable 
CROSS APPLY 
  MyFunction(MyTable.field1, MyTable.field2) as ExpensiveFunction
```

Provided that `ExpensiveFunction` is an inline (i.e. not multi-statement) function, and that it only returns one row, it will usually scale better than scalar functions do.

If you use a multi-statement table valued function that returns multiple rows, it *will* call `ExpensiveFunction` for every row. Generally, though, you shouldn't have TVFs that return records that will later be discarded.

Inline functions, on the other hand, since they can be expanded inline, as if they were a SQL macro, will only call `ExpensiveFunction` when necessary, like the view.

In the example in your question, **`ExpensiveFunction` should only be called when necessary**. To be sure, though, you should definitely **look at your query execution plan** and **use an SQL profiler** to optimize performance.